# Merge DataFrame by Mutliindex column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 simple DataFrames I need to merge. Both have one column in common and I want to use this column as index.

```
>>> df1
   A  B
   a  b
0  0  3
1  1  4
2  2  5
>>> df2
   A  C
   a  c
0  2  6
1  1  7
2  0  8
```

And I want something like

```
>>> df
   A  B  C
   a  b  c
0  0  3  6
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
```

This does not work

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=(('A','a')), right_on=(('A','a')))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @amarion, Please post your solution as an answer, not in the question itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your first idea with selectimg columns to parameters `left_on` and `right_on`:

```
df = (df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1[('A','a')], right_on=df2[('A','a')], suffixes=('','_'))
         .drop(('A_','a'), 1))
print (df)
   A  B  C
   a  b  c
0  0  3  8
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  6
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really simple

```
>>> df1 = df1.set_index(('A','a'))
>>> df2 = df2.set_index(('A','a'))
>>> df = df1.merge(df2, right_index=True, left_index=True)
>>> df
        B  C
        b  c
(A, a)
0       3  8
1       4  7
2       5  6
>>> df.reset_index()
   A  B  C
   a  b  c
0  0  3  8
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  6
```